# IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains filePath

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

Trying to open an image in the default gallery app. I can't resolve this issue following the steps:
My file path is `/data/data/{applicationName}/cache/file.jpg`

Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(filePath);
     intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext()
                            .getPackageName() + ".provider", file),"image/*"); 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Manifest:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
          android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

I've tried changing the path and name in provider_paths but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace:

```
<external-path
    name="external_files"
    path="." />
```

with:

```
<cache-path name="external_files" />
```

as your path seems to be in `getCacheDir()`.